# OnClickListener in custom dialog

Tags: java, android, view, dialog

This is what is working correctly

```
>>The user swipes on a part of the main activity ui we will call the MainTitleBar.
>>This creates a dialog with stuff in it
=----------------------------------------------------------------------------=
```

Now I need to make it so when someone clicks on the buttons or imageviews within that dialog STUFF happens. I cannot figure out for the life of me how to handle this.

Code I have currently inside the maintitlebar.java class (which extends view) and is the view they are swiping on to create the dialog box.

--- bunch of stuff like ui stuff and swipe calculations etc

```
public void onDownSwipe() {
        // custom dialog object created
        Dialog ntd = new Dialog(getContext(),R.style.lightbox_dialog);
        ntd.setContentView(R.layout.create_task_dialog);
        ntd.show();
        ImageView cancelbutton = (ImageView) ntd.findViewById(R.id.cancelbutton);
        cancelbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnclickListener(){


            public void onClick(View v) {
                ntd.dismiss();
            }
         }  

        );
```

In the xml for the dialog, the create_task_dialog is the overall xml for the dialog.
the cancelbutton (id) is the id for the cancel button (which is properly added with + sign into resource file).

Should I be putting the onclicklistener and clicky stuff somewhere else in my code?
So confused as to how to make my dialog buttons/imageviews clickable.

THANKS!

Comment: hmmm?? There are many questions in your posts...Im sorry but I got lost. Could you please improve on the post in a way so it is easier to figure out? thanks

Comment: Is onDownSwipe being called? How about adding debug statements to both it, and where onClick is called.

Comment: onDownSwipe is called when the user swipes which is working as requred. Then it creates a dialog. That dialog has imageviews/buttons which I need to have do stuff. How do I do that?